# How do I parse a response form a server using Strongloop loopback android Library?

Tags: android, json, parsing, strongloop

I am currently parsing data from a server, using Strongloop loopback, but i am parsing the data via a jsonRequest and I was wondering how I can parse the data using a Strongloop request. I checked out the android docs on Strongloop but they are not very descriptive, also their example app is broken. Any ideas?
All i have done so far is get this far,

```
RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
         "http://example.com/api");
```

I really have no idea what the doc is saying, 
for instance in,

```
ModelRepository productRepository = adapter.createRepository("product");
Model pen = productRepository.createObject(ImmutableMap.of("name", "Awesome Pen"));
```

what is going on here?

Comment: I updated it I am having alot of trouble understanding how to parse with it

Comment: What's going on in the second block of code is that it's cresting a repository object from a string, then creating a model object out of a ImmutableMap that has a key and a value...

Comment: Reading the [API documentation](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-sdk-android/api/index.html) may help. But the general idea is that you don't need to parse anything yourself. You define an extension of a Model object, then get a Repository for those models, then you can create, delete, get, etc.